# Ruby Benchmark: mocking call to external API in script

Tags: ruby, performance, benchmarking

I want to benchmark a Ruby service who output formatted Json out of Rails models.

```
#!/usr/bin/env/rails r

require 'benchmark'

sample_project = Project.last
formatter = Formatter.new(sample_project)

Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|
  x.report('creation:') { Formatter.new(sample_project) }
  x.report('output:') { formatter.output }
end
```

This script fails, because `formatter.output` calls an external API and can't get an answer.

My code is slow without that call. My first reflex was to try to stub that call, but I can't succeed to set it up. And I don't know if it's the best way to set up my benchmark.

What is the best strategy to adopt here?

Comment: why not use a library like webmock?

Comment: I'm using a home made gem to talk to that API, it would be way easier for me to stub a method, rspec style.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to stub some method is to reopen your class (which makes externall API call) and override required methods

e.g. put it after loading your files and before running benchmark

```
Formatter.class_eval do
  def make_api_call
    {foo: 'bar'} # some stubbed values
  end
end
```